# Layout problems using base font size in IE6/7 - the em/px bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

So i just realized that setting the base font size to 10px, and using em's as my size of measurement did not go to well. IE does not stick to 10px base font-size, so my site kinda explodes in IE7/6...

Heres a screenshot of firefox:[image]

---

And this is IE7: [image]

So does any one happen to know if there are any quick fixes? or do i need to convert all em to px? And if so, is there a quick way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [IE7 JS](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). this may fix your problem,